# Diferencia entre RealmList y RealmResults en Realm.io de Android

Tags: android, realm

¿Cuales son las diferencias en devolver los datos de una consulta `Realm.io` que estén en forma de `RealmList` o `RealmResults`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te dejo la documentación de [RealmResults](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html) y [RealmList](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html) donde puedes ver las diferencias de cada uno y te hago un pequeño resumen de lo básico que debes saber:

- `ReamList` se usa para hacer relaciones one-to-many de objetos de `Realm` y básicamente es un `ArrayList` que puede ser usado dentro de un RealmObject  cosa que `RealmResults` no puede.
- `RealmResults` siempre será el resultado de una consulta y solo tiene referencias de los de los objetos que te devuelve dicha consulta.